# buildozer error in google colab with kivy

Tags: python, kivy, google-colaboratory, kivymd, buildozer

I tried to convert my python calculator that i made into an .apk, but after I edited my buildozer.spec file, and ran !buildozer -v android debug in google Colab, I got this error.

My error.
[https://pastebin.com/qDsC9qgS]

[my kivy and kivy-garden versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHZGY.png)

This was my buildozer file.
[https://pastebin.com/s8Czn0uV]

I have tried looking at multiple tutorials but even though they were all different, they still didn't seem to solve the problem.

Please help

Comment: Hello   and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include your code/error log/configuration in your question and not as a link to an external site (or a picture).